# Webpack not accepting POST requests

Tags: angularjs, angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm currently working on an Angular 2 web application which communicates with an API. In the application the user is able to choose a payment option and the API will return the url to the payment service.

The problem is that the payment service uses POST to go to the confirmation page which WebPack does not accept (for some reason it only allows GET requests) and we get the following error:

`Cannot POST /selection/payment-method`

Does anybody know how we could configure that WebPack allows POST requests also? I've contacted the payment provider but it is not possible to do a GET request instead of POST.

Thanks

Comment: Are you running `webpack-dev-server` in production?

Comment: @robertklep No not in production on our production server we have nginx installed which serves the static html, js and css. But when we are developing we need a way to develop the confirmation page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @robertklep who send me the link to the proxy documentation we found a way to deal with it. What we needed to do was instead of handling the POST request we needed to transform it someway into a GET. After reading some more of the documentation we came across the `setup:` property for your `webpack-dev-server` configuration.

With the `setup:` property you get the expressjs object and you are able to catch urls before it hits the route that says `Cannot POST /url/to/page`.

We ended up with this:

```
devServer: {
    setup: function(app) {
        app.post('/selection/payment-method', function(req, res) {
          res.redirect('/selection/payment-method');
        });
    },
}
```

This way we got a GET request instead of POST and our application does an API request to check if the payment succeeded or not.

This is only used in development!

Comment: How would you do something similar in production?

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Sven's answer, modification to the setup so that it works for POST all throughout

Add dependencies on `body-parser`, `sync-request` and add require dependencies on both in your webpack.config.js

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var request = require('sync-request');
```

In devServer part of webpack.config.js

```
devServer: {
        setup: function(app) {
            app.use(bodyParser.json());
            app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
                extended: true
            }));

            app.post(/^\/(URL1|URL2|URL3)\//, function(req, res) {
                var serviceCallResponse = request('POST', 'your app server url here' + req.originalUrl, {
                    json:req.body
                });
                res.send(serviceCallResponse.getBody('utf8'));
            });
        },
        proxy: {
            '*/other URLs proxy/*': 'your app server url here'
        }
}
```

Change URL1/2 to the URLs you want to proxy and you place your app servers address.

This will work for all sorts of POST request proxy (working on json payload)

Answer (score 1):

A hackish way to at least not get 404 errors is to proxy requests to `/selection/payment-method` and send back an empty response (or whatever content you want, I think that `res` is an instance of Express's [Response](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res) class) for those, by adding the following to `webpack.config.js`:

```
devServer: {
  proxy: {
    '/selection/payment-method': {
      bypass : (req, res) => res.end()
    }
  }
}
```

Documentation [here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#bypass-the-proxy).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! After checking out some more settings in the documentation you sent, we've "hacked" it in a different way. With the proxy the request is killed no matter if it's a GET or a POST request. 

If you use `setup:` instead of `proxy:` you get the express object and you could do stuff when it's a post or put or anything else. I added sample code to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Webpack-dev-server is only intended as your front-end server only, eg. to serve your static assets. Therefore only GET requests are supported.

If you would want to use a proxy or backend server, then you should implement this. You can use [Express](https://expressjs.com/) for this.
See [how you can setup basic routing](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html).

Comment: Our application only serves static assets and at the confirmation page it does an API request to check if the payment was successful. In production we use nginx to serve the static html, js and css, there it goes fine. Too bad the webpack-dev-server does not allow it.

Thanks for the answer anyway!

Comment: This is not a very good answer. The entire purpose of the proxy is to proxy to a data server during dev time. It doesn't do much good to proxy GET and not POST. It does actually proxy POST most of the time, I've only seen it fail in certain cases.

Comment: Proxying data is one of the most fundamental features of webpack-dev-server. I'm sorry but I had to downvote your answer.