# Is Vue.js Incompatible With Serving POST Requests?

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js, single-page-application, vue-router

I'm trying to do [thing] with a Vue.js project created with Vue CLI. [Thing] is not super-important to this question, so I'll omit it for the sake of brevity. I've noticed when I run the local web server for this project with

`$ npm run serve`

that GET requests work just fine; but POST requests give me a 404 - "Cannot POST". I need to be able to do both.

Using [Express](https://expressjs.com), it's straightforward to serve the same page with both GET and POST by simply adding `router.post(...)` in addition to the default `router.get(...)`. However, in Vue.js this seems difficult.

I've spent some time playing with [Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/), but poring over the documentation I haven't found a configuration option to tell it "Here's how to respond to a POST request" - it seems to require GET.

But maybe I'm trying to pound a square peg into a round hole. Vue.js is geared toward applications that run in the browser, and browsers send GET requests (For the moment I'm not interested in form submissions...) where POST requests tend to be more of a web app/integration/back end kind of a thing.

What do you guys think - is there something obvious I'm missing, or should I do this the "easy" way and switch to Express?

UPDATE: My "problem" is not Vue.js, specifically - it's the binary vue-cli-service, which *definitely* listens for GETs, but not POSTs. (GETs from Postman succeed; POSTs from Postman fail.) If I build for deployment, webpack turns the project into HTML/JS/CSS, which is served by a different web server and POSTs work just fine - it's just in dev mode where vue-cli-service is serving my application locally that I can't use POST requests.

Is there an undocumented way to make vue-cli-service respond to POST requests? I've scoured the documentation but haven't found anything. I'm not sure how to make another web server serve a Vue.js project, because the webpack configuration is...complex.

Comment: Vue is a frontend framework and not a backend one like express. The router probably only serves GET requests, because anything else looks more like an API

Comment: Put another way: You need to setup middleware in express (or whatever server you have) to handle incoming POST requests; the server is always the first contact with any request. This is not an issue with Vue itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been nearly two weeks since I posted this question, but I didn't even post the question until I'd been struggling with the problem on my own for a week. I finally came to a solution after much head-desking and more dead ends than it would be healthy for my blood pressure to recount. Here it is:

1. Deciding perhaps my best bet was to look at [the vue-cli source code](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli), I happened to notice it includes documentation
2. The README.md file under docs/config is a bit sparse-looking in what it says about the devserver option, but it also mentions that *All options for webpack-dev-server are supported*. Ooh.
3. The [Webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverbefore) shows a devserver.before option that allows you to *access the Express app object and add your own custom middleware to it*
4. This allows you to intercept the POST and redirect it as a GET
5. [Which this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636615/webpack-not-accepting-post-requests), who was having the exact same problem as I was, ultimately did. (Note that he used devserver.setup, which does the same thing, but is deprecated in favor of devserver.before.) In vue.config.js, include

```
devServer: {
    before: function(app) {
        app.post('/about.html', function(req, res) {
          res.redirect('/about.html');
        });
    },
}
```

Comment: Great idea. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but this would only work in a dev environment where you have webpack acting as your server? So wouldn't work in production?

Comment: I believe that's correct.

For my purposes, the minimized production build was working just fine, except that it takes 5-7 minutes between uploading the new version and seeing it take effect. Not terrible for a real deployment, but intolerable when developing.

Comment: Mike, thank you for being so vocal on StackOverflow. You working out your problem 'out loud' really helped me with a similar dilemma.

Comment: @coltoneakins You're welcome! Very happy I was able to help someone. 

Answer (score 3):

Vue Router is not receiving a (GET) request and responding, it is simply reading the current URL and inserting the corresponding component. So in short, no, there is no POST request handler... I'd argue it's not even handling GET requests either, just reading the URL which looks like a GET request.

If you are trying to POST between pages inside your app, Vuex is what you want.
If you are trying to POST to your app from outside, having an actual server listening for requests which you can ping will be easier (ie Express).

There *may* be a way to use [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to do this from your app. It can listen to responses from POST requests, so if it were listening I don't see why it couldn't receive. However, I suspect you'd have to listen to a port from the machine where your app is running which would be a major security issue (if a client's browser/OS/Antivirus even let you).

Comment: It is receiving a GET request. I can verify this with Postman: GETs succeed; POSTs fail.

Comment: It's just semantics. A request/response pattern is what happens between clients and servers. Typically, a GET request is requesting a certain resource from a server which the server then provides. The way Vue works isn't quite the same as the whole app is "provided" and then rendered on the client side with Vuex managing a little window within that. If you use Nuxt however, you can do this on server-side and get a typical GET pattern.