# Angular2 not receiving POST requests

Tags: angular, post, payment-gateway

In my `Angular2` application, I've configured a `payment-gateway` and the payment API will return to a URL (that I defined in my code) with a transaction Id. The problem is that the payment service uses POST to go to the confirmation page which angular2 is not accepting and I'm getting this error:

Cannot POST /url/payment-method

If I change return URL to server API, I successfully receive this call on my server, but then I couldn't get any way to send a call on front-end and change my application URL.

Does anybody know how can I resolve this issue? I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39636615) but it is using web-pack that I'm not using, so I'm totally stuck here. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: you are not supposed to do calls to the front-end. use `router.navigate` or `router.navigateByUrl` to change browser url and open another page after ajax request is complete.

Comment: web-pack is the solution that worked for me

Comment: @Andrei I've form post that actually reload payment site on form submission.and If i navigate to another page, how can I prevent user by using application, till transaction is successfully completed?

Comment: @AthulRaj but I don't have Web-pack in my application.